# How do I programmatically set an Angular 2 form control value?

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I change an Angular 2 control from code?

When I do it like this:

```
control.value = "new value";
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property value of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `updateValue` method:

```
control.updateValue("new value");
```

**update:**

You can now use `setValue`:

```
control.setValue("new value");
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cast the `AbstractControl` to a `Control` before you have access to the `updateValue` method:

```
(<Control>yourControl).updateValue(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both `updateValue` and `updateValueAndValidity` to update the value of a control and also trigger validators / calculate state.

Here is a sample:

```
control.updateValue("new value");
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: I checked the source code and it seems that updateValueAndValidity is called at the end of updateValue anyway. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts

Answer (score 1):

In the final version of Angular 2, the `.changeValue(newValue: string)` method was removed and exchanged for `.patchValue(newValue: string)`

so you can do `control.patchValue('your new value goes here');`